# Change the pivot Table filter using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-addins

I have a pivot table which contains the "CoB Date" field as shown.
I am trying to create a macro which automatically changes the date as per the user input.
I've written the following macro code. But it shows the error:

*Unable to get PivotFields property of the PivotTable class*

Can any one help me with this?
Note: Assume that Date Format is not an issue

**Code:**

```
Sub My_macro()
    Dim num as String
    num = InputBox(Prompt:="Date", Title:="ENTER DATE")
    Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1") _
        .PivotFields("CoB Date").CurrentPage = num
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could share the code you have and tell us what errors and where they occur...

Comment: @Rory: Yeah, I've added the vba code as well

Comment: To get what you want, 1st you have to make sure the user enters the correct date format. Once you solve that, you can simple use the Pivot Table Objects CurrentPage method to update the currently selected date. Btw, we are talking about normal pivots here right? not Power Pivots? Your code didn't work because you are trying to access a Range which is part of the Pivot.

Comment: @L42: Yeah, normal pivots only. I'll try to figure out in the way you've mentioned. Thanks

Comment: Cool. If ever you got stuck in the process, update your question.

Comment: @L42: I've tried using updating the PivotTableField "CoB Date" using current page method. However, excel shows the following error. I couldn't solve it : "Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable class"

Comment: I tested your code and it works on my end. See my example.

Comment: @L42: The sheet contains some 20,000 odd rows. And date takes at most 30 values. Does having those many rows can be an issue ?

Comment: I've run into the same problem. No matter what I do, I can't set the Pivot Table filter programatically. I'm starting to hate VBA.

Comment: Got the same error ... what in the world

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE: Before setting a PageField through VBA, it is vitally important to run the .ClearAllFilters method on the PivotField first. If a PageField has already been selected, then the line of code for setting a PageField will do one of two things: If a PivotItem can be found with that name, it is set as the PageField as expected. However, if a PivotItem can't be found, then excel WILL RENAME THE CURRENT PIVOT ITEM TO THE SPECIFIED VALUE! (It does this because .Name is the default property.) Clearing filters first will instead force an error to be thrown if the pivot item does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

As commented the exact same code works on my end.

```
Sub My_macro()
    Dim num As String
    num = InputBox(Prompt:="Date", Title:="ENTER DATE")
    Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1") _
        .PivotFields("CoB Date").CurrentPage = num
End Sub
```

Suppose you have a data like this:

[image]

When you run the macro, it will prompt for a date:

[image]

And then after pressing ok, the result would be:

[image]

Take note that we assumed that entering of date is not an issue.
So we used a simple data which will eliminate that and so your code works.
The probable issue you're dealing with is if the dates have *Time Stamp*.
And based on your screen shot, that is the case.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried a lots of times and I am still getting the same error that "Unable to access PivotTableField property". I think it's not detecting the "CoB Date" field. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with "Unable to get PivotFields property of the PivotTable class".

I figured out that while my pivot table was the only one on that sheet (or in the workbook for that matter) it was not "PivotTable1".  It was "PivotTable4" most likely because I had created and deleted 3 others beforehand.

To find out the name of your pivot table, and change it if you want, just right click anywhere in your pivot table and then select "Pivot Table Options".  You will see the "PivotTable Name" right at the top and can rename it from there.

Additionally, I was having issues with this same error when trying to change one of the filters.  When I referenced the field using:

```
Sheets("mySheetName").PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("myFieldName")
```

it would throw the same error as above.  It turned out I had 3 spaces at the end of my field name.  The way I found this out may was to loop through all my filter fields displaying a MsgBox for each until I found it.  The following code is how I did that and hopefully may help someone with a similar issue:

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField

Set pt = Sheets("mySheetName").PivotTables("PivotTable4")
For Each pf In pt.PivotFields
    MsgBox ("FieldName: [" & pf.Name & "] with a length of: " & Len(pf.Name) & " and a trimmed length of: " & Len(Trim(pf.Name)))
Next pf
```

Hope this helps someone!